# Why i do not have Page Builder on magento 2.4.3?

Tags: magento2.4.3, page-builder

Why I do not have the Page Builder on Magento 2.4.3 Open Source?
I installed ma 2.4.3 and also tried 2.4.3-p1 and I don't get Page builder to get activate
I removed and re-installed Magento 2.4.3 with a different version from 2.4.3 and up and I can't see how to get the advanced content tools.

Check the picture.[image: this is the what i get with magento 2.4.3 version]

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the **vendor** folder and clear the composer cache:

```
rm -rf vendor
composer clear-cache
```

Then run the following commands from Magento root directory:

```
composer install
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked.

Comment: Glad to help. Cheers!

Comment: Hello friend Tu Van, quick question, i uninstalled magento from my server and i re-installed it same version and i run those commands but no lucky to install pagebuilder anymore, do i have to add any repository? any suggest, thank you in advance

Comment: Hi friend! I think you have a mistake when installing Magento. Let me know the steps you did to install Magento, I'll help you fix this issue and your other issue (Inventory modules). The latest Magento version is 2.4.5-p1, do you want to install that version instead of 2.4.3?

Comment: does this version 2.4.5-p1 has page builder? Thanks Tu Van

Comment: yes, Magento version >=2.4.3 included Page builder in the code base. So, let me know the steps you did to install Magento, and I'll help you fix this issue and your other issue (Inventory modules)

Comment: well, i download magento 2.4.3 from here https://github.com/magento/magento2/releases and uploaded it to my root path and then composer install and then bin/magento setup:install \
--base-url=http://yourdomain.com \
--db-host=localhost \
--db-name=b_s \
--db-user=b_s \
--db-password=passwordhere \
--admin-firstname=admin \
--admin-lastname=admin \
--admin-email=your email here \
--admin-user=as \
--admin-password=Magento@2008 \
--language=en_US \
--currency=USD \
--timezone=America/Chicago \
--use-rewrites=1

Comment: You shouldn't install Magento in that way, should use Composer to install it instead. I've written more detail in your Inventory post.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest this module instead [Goomento - Magento Page Builder](https://github.com/Goomento/PageBuilder) free and compatible builder to any stores, which I believe you can choose over Magento Builder

Comment: can i install goomento to magento 2.3.5-p1?

Comment: wow, this is what i been looking for. thanks a lot. love it.